# Django: Validate GET request

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have written a few simple API endpoints (without Django REST). I have problems figuring out how to validate the input data.

```
class CarTypeForm(forms.Form):
    car_type= forms.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(6)], required=False
    )

def car_data_as_json(request):
    """
    API Endpoint
    """

    # Receive and validate variables from get request
    car_type= request.GET.get("car_type", 0)
    car_type_form = CarTypeForm()
    car_type_form.car_type = int(car_type)
    if car_type_form.is_valid():
        do something
        return JsonResponse(something)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'err': 'invalid car_type'}, status=400)
```

I don't understand why `if car_type_form.is_valid():` is not True despite the value being 5 for example.

Endpoint is called by javascript to an url: `/api/car_data/?car_type=<number>`

I'm using Django 2.1

Comment: Why are you using GET and not POST? What does your template look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the form with your data before calling `is_valid`:

```
car_type_form = CarTypeForm({'car_type': car_type})
```